# Error in Angular ,npm install -g @angular/cli

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm

i gettin a error , i wanna setup to angular but i didn't solve this error , this error only happens in angular, i looked order error but i didn't found

```
enter code here
C:\Users\Rıdvan Demirhan>node -v
v14.17.0

C:\Users\Rıdvan Demirhan>npm -v
6.14.13
```

Error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5INMj.png)

Comment: it says you hav some files leftover from previous installations of angular, better clear them manually and retry.

Comment: You can try `npm install -g @ angular / cli` outside the nodeJS directory

Comment: You can follow exactly as the error message instructs.

Comment: @tunggggg They are attempting to install the package `@angular/cli` globally. Their working directory is irrelevant.

Comment: @tunggggg C:\Users\Rıdvan Demirhan>npm install -g @angular/cli. I tried on the cmd but it didn't work